# Prove that $D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : \nabla f(x)=0 \}$ is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Prove that $D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : \nabla f(x)=0 \}$ is convex, where
>   $f$ is convex $C^1$ function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

If $y\in D$ then $f$ has a local minimum in $y$ (from convexivity). I already proved that a local minimum of a convex function is in fact its global minimum. Now let $m:=f(y)$. We notice that in order to show that $D$ is convex, it's enough to show that $M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:f(x)=m\}$ is convex.

Let $\epsilon\in[0,1]$ and $x_1, x_2 \in M$. We have:

$$m \le f(\epsilon x_1+(1-\epsilon)x_2)\le\epsilon f(x_1)+(1-\epsilon)f(x_2)=m$$

So $f(\epsilon x_1+(1-\epsilon)x_2)=m$ and $\epsilon x_1+(1-\epsilon)x_2$ is in $M$ and thus $M$ is convex.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Since $f$ is convex, it follows that $\{x | f(x) \le m\}$ is convex. Also, $f$ just needs to be differentiable, not $C^1$.

Comment: My question is if my "proof" is correct...

Comment: Yes, it is. Nicely done.